# Profile manager pending on some devices

Tags: apple-id, osx-server, system-settings, profile-manager

I have this problem that most of the options in the system preferences are greyed out, even when I log in as an admin. 
But I need to log in to my iCloud account to get some software to run on these machines. So I changed the restrictions payload and tried to push it. 
But for some reasons only 4 of the 12 Macs will update the settings.

All Macs are turned on and connected to the local network and the internet.

I tried to figure out if any settings on the machines 1-4 are different from 5-12. The IP is manually inserted with the same DNS server address. They are all running on 10.10.5 and even the caching seems to work. The protocol on the server does not give me back any error message. 
I can not even remove the device from profile manager.

What could it be? Port problem? Certificate?

I don't know what to search for. Any suggestions how to get into system preferences? Terminal works if I log in as admin.

Answer (score 1):

As an admin you may be able to bypass the managed preference settings. Log out and then back in while holding the `Option` key. If allowed you'll see a dialog allowing you to disable managed preferences.

As far as the clients not receiving the profiles check the system.log file for errors. Look for entries from mdmclient. On the server, check the Profile Manager logs in Server.app or in `/Library/Logs/ProfileManager/` probably starting with the `profilemanager.log` file.

Is this a user-level profile or a device-level profile? I think user user-level profiles are only installed when the user logs in.

If all else fails you can try removing all profiles:

```
sudo profiles -D
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! 

Forgot to check that I can check the system.log ... It seems that there is an error validating the certificate. 
I think it is a user-level profile. I have a group with "iMacs User" (the payloads are here) in that group are 12 users "mac1-12" and each of them is paired with one device. 
From admin I tried 
`cd /user/mac11`
 `/usr/bin/profiles -I -F "../certificate.mobileconfig"`
Which didn't change anything.
Login with pressed alt key did not change anything either.

Comment: Can you post the error that you see in system.log?

Comment: ´Sep  3 13:24:31 iMac11s-iMac.fritz.box mdmclient[68]: *** ERROR *** [Daemon:0] Sending 'Idle' request to server (Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1205 "Der Server „weimarpedia-server.local“ hat das Zertifikat nicht akzeptiert." UserInfo=0x******** {NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrust 0x******* [0x*******]>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9831, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff92a425ae0 "Der Server „*****-server.local“ hat das Zertifikat nicht akzeptiert.", NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(` german: "The Server `***-server.local´ does not accept the certificate.